# What is the difference between JSP and Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp

I  sometimes wonder what is the difference between JSP and Spring?

These are used for to server. Right?

Spring is a Framework and JSP creates Java Servlets?

I know this, but I do not know to distinguish them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As defined by Wikipedia:

> The Spring Framework is an application framework and inversion of
>   control container for the Java platform.

Now, to be honest, that is a lot take in, the part that you need to focus on at this stage is **Spring is an application framework**.

What does "application framework" mean? Also, from Wikipedia:

> an application framework consists of a
>   software framework used by software developers to implement the
>   standard structure of application software.

In other words, an application framework provides a structure or flow for programmers to follow when coding an application.

Now that is great BUT how does this relate to JSP?

There are a lot of ways to use the Spring framework, a common use is web applications. Spring provides the Spring MVC implementation for this.

Spring MVC, implements the Model View Controller (MVC) application pattern.

And JSP, Java Server Pages, is a View technology. That is the way the framework serves views towards the client's browser.

So when asking what is the difference between, JSP and Spring. The question is a bit like asking what is the difference between a car and a wheel? Spring is the "frame the car is built-in" and the wheel is a specific part.

**In short:**
Both technologies are used in creating an application, Spring provides the flow, and JSP provides the way we represent our web page.